# Remainder operation in cvxpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

Is there any built in function to compute the remainder of a variable in cvxpy? For instance, the following example code:

```
m = 3
n = 2
k = 5
A = cp.Variable((m,n),boolean=True)
B = np.ones((1,m))
C = np.ones(n)
constraints = []
objective = cp.Maximize((B@A%2)@C)
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
optimal_value = prob.solve()
```

gives error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'MulExpression' and 'int'
```

Because of the % operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder `r = a mod n`, with `a ≥ 0`, can be found as:

```
  a = q*n + r      (assume n is constant) 
  q ∈ {0,1,...}    (integer variable, non-negative}
  r ∈ {0,..,n-1}   (integer variable between 0 and n-1)
```

This is just a linear constraint. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.

Comment: Thank you! I created 2 variables q and r and imposed a-2*q-r==0 in the constraints. Then I used r as remainder. It's slow, but it works